# Why does the trimethylammonium cation have a larger -I effect than the ammonium cation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, ions

Why does $\ce{N(CH_3)_3^+}$ have a larger $-I$ effect than $\ce{NH_3^+}$?

Since the methyl group is good at donating electrons it would stabilize the charge on nitrogen atom, decreasing its potential to withdraw electrons hence its $-I$ effect.

I can't figure out why its the other way around. Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: Are the groups in a gaseous phase or in a polar solvent..? The choice of phases in case of these groups changes everything.

Comment: @BhavyaSharma nothing as such is mentioned in the question. The question just wants me to find the group with highest -I effect

Comment: Methyl groups donate inductively only into empty-p-orbital cations (e.g. carbenium ions). Ammonium cations cannot profit from that stabilisation.

Comment: @Jan Oh I didn't know that, thank you! So basically inductive effect from methyl or hydrogen groups doesn't operate here. Then what is the factor that influences the stability of these ions?

Comment: @Jan That's not and inductive effect though, that's hyperconjugation.

Comment: This question was answered a year ago at https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/88185/justifying-the-tremendous-%E2%88%92i-effect-of-trimethylammonium-group-by-molecular-orbi/135045. The ring donates a pi electron to N and one CH3 group hyperconjugates (in reverse). The effect is demonstrated by the strong meta and deactivation effect typical of pi deactivators; NH3+ is only a weak deactivator and therefore not a pi actor.

Answer (score 3):

$\ce{N(CH3)3+}$ has more -I than $\ce{NH3+}$
, this irony happens because if you consider
$\ce{N-CH3}$ bond and $\ce{N-H}$ bond,  which is more polar?

Of course $\ce{N-H}$ bond will be more polar  due to more difference in electronegativity  value,  so that implies electron density will be more on $\ce{N}$ in $\ce{NH3+}$ than $\ce{N}$ on $\ce{N(CH3)3+}$.

And therefore since electron density is less on $\ce{N}$ of $\ce{N(CH3)3+}$ , it will have greater -I effect.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is that the methyl  though gives electron via +I effect in case of H it is easy to cleave the N-H bond for nitrogen and release proton and take the electron pair from hydrogen but with C it being more electronegative than H the same is not possible .

Comment: But why is bond cleavage required?

Comment: to disperse the +ve charge from more electronegative atom to less electronegative atoms